# Can I get a second chance to close a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I was attempting to vote to close a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156110/aromaticity-of-cyclopropene-anion) as a duplicate, but when I tried copying and pasting a link to the duplicate reference I somehow got the link wrong. Seeing this I retracted the vote to close, intending to try again; but I am not allowed to cast the vote. What can I do now? And, since retraction causes me to lose my vote, what could/should I have done to correct the duplication link?

Comment: If the option is closed just add a comment suggesting the linked question as a duplicate.

Comment: I did that but would rather have the vote itself back. Is there any way to regain it, or do I have to be extra careful next time?

Comment: I think you just have to be careful. That is probably a feature built into the machine ;-) Once you retract a vote you typically lose it until an edit has been made. This is probably to simplify coding as it occurs because someone is not allowed to vote twice unless an edit is made.

Comment: Tried to make my own edits, did not work. Assuming a different editor is required, here is [the question in which I lost the vote](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156110/aromaticity-of-cyclopropene-anion).

Comment: I went ahead and closed it. You might also ping a mod or flag the question if this happens again.

Comment: IIRC you can cast closevote on the same post after some fixed time (a month maybe). If I were you I wouldn't retract, just make a comment about choosing wrong dupe.

Comment: @Mithoron That will only apply if the vote ages away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no definitive proof of what I am about to write and I might be a bit rusty on the details because it's a situation that doesn't happen that often.

I vaguely remember that if you retract a close vote it is gone. I am not aware of any way to get it back. A small caveat might be that the question is closed, then reopened, and then you might be able to cast another vote. But no guarantee on that as there are also built-in measures to prevent open-close ping-pong.

When closing with a duplicate question, you'll typically get a preview, so please check this carefully in order to avoid these situations.

I think it was a good idea to retract the vote as it avoids that others will have to check something that does not apply. Additionally it prevents that the question is closed for the wrong reasons.

I suggest for situations like these, that you post a comment akin to the one that would normally be generated automatically. You have done so, which is good, but it might still get unnoticed.
Please raise a custom flag with the link to the duplicate question, so that the moderators can handle this on a case by case basis.

Comment: Thanks. You can see the question was closed; the duplication claim was clear-cut if only I had not somehow messed up my linking.

Comment: @Oscar I just wanted to make it more visible that commenting, then flagging is the best option in those cases, i.e. in general.

Comment: The close vote is blocked for some number of weeks, but can be remade once that "cool down" period expires.

Comment: @nij Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I may have mixed up the info on expired CV, as opposed to retracted CV. Double-checking now.